# Report Server - Unable to Change Name of Folder

Tags: reporting-services

I am unable to change the name of a folder on the report server. I am trying to do so through the web interface. The name of the folder is Audit_Reports. I want to chanage it to Audit Reports (space instead of underscore). However, when I try to do this I get the following error: "The folder, report, resource, model or data source /Audit_Reports already exists."

I am able to change it to Audit-Reports. Then when I try to change it from Audit-Reports to Audit Reports it give me the same error except it says Audit-Reports already exists. I also changed it to Audit-Report without the s and then to Audit Reports but that did not work either.

This obviously is not a big deal, but it is really bothering me and hopefully someone out there smarter than me knows the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't repro this issue on SSRS 2008 R2 SP1.  What version are you running.

Comment: We are on R2. I also think that we have the latest service pack.